# Flutter barcode scanner that allows for customization

Tags: flutter

I am using the following flutter package: https://pub.dev/packages/barcode_scan to implement a barcode scanner, however, this does not allow me to customize the colors. Is there a way to customize this?

This is how the scanner is used. As seen, there is no way to customize it, it only has one method called `scan`.

```
await BarcodeScanner.scan().then((barcode) { print(barcode); }
```

Comment: Hi, I have the same need. could you find a customizable barcode scanner?

Answer (score 0):

There are several different code scanners, some of them allow customisation or simply are just a basic camera preview with no graphics. That would probably fit your needs.

Have you tried this one? https://pub.dev/packages/qr_code_scanner

You can position the view whichever way you want and customise your app normally.

Comment: I tried the plugin, it can be styled very good yes, but  it is very bad at scanning, it cannot detect 90% of barcodes correctly and gives wrong output (if it detects the barcode).